Why unlink in Perl deletes the file before displaying it although I call unlike after
Image file deleted after display, not before.
I upload a file using Perl's file upload. The upload works fine, it is is the intended upload directory. In the same script, I display the file (it is an image file) and that works ok too. What I want to do is to delete the file after I show it, but when I do that I get a broken link and the image is (of course) deleted from the directory. Tried the sleep function in between to no avail.
print "<img src=\"path_to\image\">
#sleep (5);
unlink "path\to\image\";


Just fyi, "\t" would be a tab character. I don't know why you are using backslash in your paths, but that's probably a bad idea. Perl has lots of options on quoting, e.g. single quote, and q() and qq() which can have lots of delimiters, e.g. qq##.

the normal way to create and clean up temporary files would be to put them all in a certain directory and then run something like find /my/temp/dir/ -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm {} + via cron

When you print the web page and it gets sent to the client, that can take a few seconds, especially if you send a lot more content after the link. But your code just deletes the file, hence when the browser renders the page and tries to display the image, it's already gone.
Your sleep slows down the page rendering as well, so that really may or may not help you, depending on buffering it may just make the whole page slower to load.
The real solution here would be to have another mechanism clean up such image files, e.g., delete all files at midnight, or check every hour and delete each file that has been created x minutes ago.

First of all, you aren't flushing the output.[1] It's not being sent until after the sleep and unlink.
Additionally, the server might not send the response to the client until the response is complete. That's entirely up to the server.
These are both facts that would prevent the client from receiving the response before you unlink the file.
There's also multiple sources of delays between the time the response is sent and the request for the image can be received.
Solutions
You could use an independent periodically-run job that deletes the files if they're more than a certain age.
Or you could embed the image using a data: url to avoid all of these issues.


This disables buffering:
select()->autoflush();

Or you can flush the buffer after printing using the following:
select()->flush();




Thanks. Yes it needs another mechanism. I found out that sleep() refreshes the page so the image disappears after the sleep delay. My not-so-elegant solution is to have an iframe that calls another script with just the unlink in it. It works.

Why not just delete it on a schedule? Have something that deletes everything older than 5 minutes or something?
